# rac_signalForControlEvents not signaling in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, reactive-cocoa

I have a bunch of `UICollectionViewCells` containing buttons. For some reason, my signal refuses to fire when a button is inside of a `UICollectionViewCell`. Switching to the normal `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` will work, but not the RAC signal. I've had this happen in 2 different collection views, and 2 different custom collection cells.

All I'm doing is:

```
[[cell.button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        // code to be executed here, which doesn't happen
}];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you setting `rac_signal` in `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath` or in the cell's `init`?

Comment: I have a custom setup method that gets called during `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. So yes, the buttons are there.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a ReactiveCocoa-specific problem. Can you include any relevant parts of your custom setup method in your question?

Comment: Are there any taprecognizers which can prevent this action from happening?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
[[[cell.button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
     takeUntil:cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal]
     subscribeNext:^(id x) {
         // code to be executed here, which doesn't happen
     }];
```

Comment: That would just ensure that the same cell doesn't subscribe more than once, which would be the cause of the opposite issue to the one being encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I will just comment here. It seems that there is something wrong with the button instance that is causing the signal not to fire. How are your buttons instantiated and where in the `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath` are you subscribing to the signal.